# WP8 QR code detection limits

Tags: windows-phone-8, qr-code

I am using a Telerik Barcode control to generate QR codes on a WP8 application and am using the built in QR code reader to decode them on other Windows Phones.

However, somewhere between v10 and v15 of the QR code, the detection starts failing

Is there a well defined set of limitations to the WP8 QR detection?

Alternately, whats the maximum amount of data I can practically pass using a QR code? v40 seems to support upto 2-3kB but I really doubt thats going to work when read by a phone camera